# PHP extract string between delimiters allow duplicates

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to get the text between two delimiters and save it into an array. I wrote this function,  the problem with this code is it removes duplicates so

```
$this->getInnerSubstring('{2}{A}{A}{A}{X}','{', '}');
```

returns an array that is like

```
[0] =>2,
[1]=>A,
[2] =>X ,
```

Yet I want:

```
[0] =>2,
[1]=>A,
[2]=>A,
[3]=>A,
[4] =>X,
```

Without Regex patterns is there a substr flag that lets me keep duplicates? what's the best approach here:

```
function getInnerSubstring($string,$start, $end){
    $s = array();
        do
         {
             $startpos = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);
             $endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos);
             $s[] = substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
                //remove entire occurance from string:
                $string =   str_replace(substr($string, strpos($string, $start), strpos($string, $end) +strlen($end)), '', $string);


        }
    while (strpos($string, $start)!== false && strpos($string, $end)!== false);


    return $s;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all()` for that:

```
$string = "{2}{A}{A}{A}{X}";
$ldelim = "{";
$rdelim = "}";

var_dump(getInnerSubstring($string, $ldelim, $rdelim));

function getInnerSubstring($string, $ldelim, $rdelim) {
    $pattern = "/" . preg_quote($ldelim) . "(.*?)" . preg_quote($rdelim) . "/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "X"
}
```

---

An alternative would be to use `preg_split()`:

```
var_dump(preg_split('({|})', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

You can put that into a function using the same way as above.

Comment: Just realized that my approach only works if 1 character is between the delimiters! So your answer is way better! (*Why 1523?* ;D Don't no just a random number)

Comment: :D ... I thought it is always 42 ..  Yeah, if there can be more than one character between the delimiters yours wouldn't work anymore. However, `preg_split()` could be used... Let me add that to my answer...

Comment: Right! `preg_split()` didn't though about that. ([*42*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173175/difference-in-giving-value-inside-function-and-outside#comment46564734_29173175) yeah, but it would be a really small book, so...)

Comment: Works great, should of used reg expressions in the first place curse you str_replace

Comment: Could you explain the `(.*?)` I understand the wildcard character but why the ?

Comment: @Edward `.` means any character except new line characters. `*` means 0 to unlimited times  and the `?` makes it lazy, so it tries only  as few times as possible

Comment: The `?` character after a `*` quantifier indicates a *non-greedy* match. If you omit it, the regex engine would consume as many characters as possible (including `}`) until it can find the last `}` in the string. Omit it for testing and you'll see.

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php .. imo that manual is pretty good.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this site already but its perfect for playing around with regexes: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @hek2mgl Just got another idea how to do it :D But your answer will still be the best

Answer (score 2):

Nice and simple:

Just changed all `{` and `}` to `{` and exploded it on it.

```
$str = "{2}{A2}{A}{A}{X}";
$str = array_filter(explode("{", str_replace(["{", "}"], ["", "{"], $str)));
print_r($str);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => A2 [2] => A [3] => A [4] => X )
```

In order to be able to recognize empty elements you could use:

```
$str = "{2}{A2}{A}{A}{}{X}";
$elements = explode('}', str_replace("{", "", $str) . PHP_EOL));
array_pop($elements);
print_r($elements);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] =>  2  [1] =>  A2  [2] =>  A  [3] =>  A  [4] =>  [5] =>  X )
```

Comment: Looks good, since it doesn't require a regex but it will output an additional empty element at the end because there will be an `}` at the end. http://3v4l.org/fo7et

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, totally didn't noticed it! Just fixed it, now it won't produce any empty entries even if there is no text in `{}`

Comment: @hek2mgl But I still love your approach much more. (Und wie war die Sonnenfinsternis in Berlin? Bewölkt? )

Comment: I you would replace the `{` by a space you could recognize empty elements. Let me edit that...

Comment: Forget about the space... That was nonsense.. simple `array_pop()` should be ok. Nein schöne Sonne aber ich hab das irgendwie verpeilt. War auch nicht merkbar dunkel