# string between function to fetch multiple strings having same start and end strings in PHP. and store them in array variable

Tags: php

i am trying to parse contents from someone others website into my PHP project using some string between function. but there are multiple strings having same 'start' and 'end' strings. so i wants all of them to be stored in an array variable.

through my string between function it returns only first string.

exp:

```
$string='afghjuyakkg';
$start_string='a';
$end_string='g';
```

my get_string_between function is:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = ' '.$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
            if ($ini == 0) return '';
            $ini += strlen($start);   
            $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
            return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }
    $result=get_string_between($string, $start_string, $end_string);
```

it should return  'f,kk'

but it returns only 'f'.
I am new to PHP so please help me.

Comment: add your code please

Comment: function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
   {
    $string = ' '.$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
     if ($ini == 0) return '';
     $ini += strlen($start);   
     $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
     return substr($string,$ini,$len);
   }

Comment: so you want to get the litter f and litter k only am i right ?

Comment: Add the code to the question please. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50552413/edit Also please include the value of `$string`.

Comment: Why are you putting a space at the start of the string? (`$string = ' '.$string;`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP extract string between delimiters allow duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176716/php-extract-string-between-delimiters-allow-duplicates)

Comment: @Gulzar have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe regex is your best option.
This captures what is between start and end and returns it to $matches[1] as an array.

```
Preg_match_all("/" . $start . "(.*?)" . $end ."/", $string, $matches);
Var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/hcCAY

Comment: but the litters' position can be trick as a litter can exist more than one time in the same string

Comment: Yes? So? Did you try the code? It's not tricky at all in my opinion

Comment: @Gulzar feel free to accept the answer as solved by clicking the tick mark left of my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
// this function is in case you want to return the second char from the start and the two chars before the last char at the end
function get_string_between($string) { // takes any string
if (strlen($string)>0) { // check if the string is not empty
    $first_litter = substr($string, 2, 1); // 2 to get first two char form the start and 1 to remove first char 
    $last_litter = substr($string, -3, -1); //-3 to get first three char form the start and -1 to remove last char 
    return ($first_litter . "," . $last_litter);
}
else
    return "string is empty";
}
```

if you want more dynamic solution based on the positions or the litter itself please say

Comment: bro... my string is changeable. there are no fixed elements in string and no fixed length.

Comment: above string was just an example. solution should be dynamic that implements to any string.

Comment: I know you want to get the last 2 litters of any string the -3 gives you the last 3 litters of any string you put and the -1 will remove the last litter so it may appear to you it's not dynamic but think about it and test it if it won't work tell me and i'll add more dynamic code

Comment: @GulzarAli do you always want the second letter form the start and the 2 litters form the end ??